# WCF Certificate permissions problems

Tags: wcf, permissions, certificate

I have a self-hosted WCF service being tested now in QA using self-signed (makecert.exe) certificates for SSL. If the web service is started using admin rights and a .BAT file, the program has no trouble starting the SSL endpoint.

But if I start the web service as a normal windows service, running as "NT Authority\System", the program will frequently (but no always?!) fail to start, throwing an error that "may not have a private key that is capable of key exchange or the process may not have access rights for the private key"

This is the makecert command I used:

```
makecert  -iv Cas_temp_Authority.pvk -n "CN=ServerName" ServerName.cer -sv 
ServerName.pvk -ic ServerName.cer -sr localmachine -ss my -sky exchange -pe -eku
1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1
```

I used this netshell command to assign the certificate to the port

```
netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:8086 certhash=755f7fcf49ff3f06d9d7e551a10ef35776f2dc57 
appid={42e1d4bf-7106-4666-90f7-4634456fb7f1} clientcertnegotiation=enable
```

I used this netshell command to set the port permissions:

```
 netsh http add urlacl url=https://+:8086/ServiceName/MethodName/ 
 user="NT Authority\System"
```

I know there is nothing wrong with the certificates or the programming code; if there was something wrong, the service would not start at all. The issue here is that it starts only as administrator using an .EXE and it will not start as a normal windows service.

I'd be grateful for any help.

Comment: You should check store location where it hosting your certificates.

Comment: Toan, The store seems OK. If the service can find the certificate when running as admin, shouldn't it find it as "NT Authority\System"? That's what is perplexing about this problem.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using the [winhttpcertcfg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384088%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  tool from microsoft?

```
winhttpcertcfg -g -c LOCAL_MACHINE\MY -s [cert common name] -a "NT Authority\System"
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that one. I think I just gave up on what I was trying to do there and created a work around.  Thanks, though.